# strange partial integration

Tags: calculus, integration, notation, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I was reading a solution to calculating some integral. one of the steps is:

$$\int xe^{-x^2}\sin(ax) dx = -\frac{1}{2}\int \sin(ax) de^{-x^2}$$

I am not familliar with the notation $de^{-x^2}$ because I normally use $du$ and write $u=....$. But in this case I understand it.

Now the next step I dont get:

$$\int \sin(ax) de^{-x^2}=-\int e^{-x^2} d\sin(ax)$$

What happens here?? I can't get the substitution $u=, du=...dx$ steps clear to do it myself

Comment: There's an integration by parts going on here, as well as changes of variables.

Comment: For the first step, see the [Riemann-Stieltjes Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Stieltjes_integral).  The second step is integration by parts and it is done incorrectly.  Were there integration limits in the original problem?

Comment: Sorry, it actually says $-\int_{-\infty}^\infty sin(ax) de^{-x^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} d\sin(ax).

Comment: that  is not strange it is you the stranger in this